# SQL Server account and login permissions for NAS?

Tags: windows, sql

We use MS SQL server express 2008 R2 to store data for our application. Recently, we've started storing the databases on a shared NAS drive. Previously, we had the sql server "log in as" built in account: local system - because our database were stored locally. To make it work with the NAS we had to change this to "this account" and have the installer enter a username and password. This makes install more complicated, as they have to know a suitable account and pw.

A customer recently tried this with a computer which had a local windows (Win7) username and password that wasn't recognised by the NAS. Even though the NAS had write permissions enabled for everyone - so the user could create files on the NAS - when SQL server was given that username and password, the server couldn't write to the NAS. Error thrown was 1317 "The specified account does not exist."

My question is why can a user who is logged in on a paticular username write to a NAS, but, SQL, using the same username can't? Is there a workaround? (this would be useful when we want to do quick demos)

Answer (score 0):

Given that SQL Server Express can only hold a very small amount of data, 4 Gigs I think, using a shared NAS is probably overkill for storage.  As to why it would work for a person and not for an account when using the same credentials, no idea.  You'd have to talk to the NAS vendor (or at least identify them) to figure that out as it's the NAS which is rejecting the connection.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has a 10GB limit for the DB, but the db can link to external files (eg videos) of any size.

Comment: This is the device in question: http://www.synology.com/products/product.php?product_name=DS2411%2B

Comment: Those videos would be outside the database then, and the application would simply point to files in a folder which the database has a reference to.  The database and the video files don't need to exist in the same location.

Comment: There are other reasons why the DB has to be on the NAS. I don't want to redesign the application just to solve a SQL login bug.

Comment: That's going to be an issue with the NAS and how it's handling authentication tokens from Windows.  SQL doesn't know anything about Windows authentication other than to hand authentication requests to the server or the domain.  There's no application redesign.  Just tell SQL Server to store the database on local disk.  The application doesn't care where the actual database sits.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - but it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Again you'll have to talk to their support about their implementation of Samba.  Samba (or at least the version they have installed) may handle tokens which are created by a service logging into an account differently than if it was a Windows user logging in interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute command before backup to connect to your shared folder at NAS:

`net use \\<NAS>\<shared-folder> <password> /user:<domain>\<user>`

...and execute after backup to disconnect:

`net use \\<NAS>\<shared-folder> /delete`

Comment: Thanks. What does this do?

Comment: ...mounting ("mapping" in Microsoft terminology) drive shares in a network environment... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_use